# Better way to handle possible nil assignment with default value?

Tags: swift

I have this code in Objective-C:

```
CGFloat constant = self.leftConstraint.constant;
```

I'd like to achieve the same thing in Swift, but this is the only way I've been able to get it to work (leftConstraint is an optional variable):

```
var leftConstraintConstant : CGFloat = 0.0
if self.leftConstraint {
    leftConstraintConstant = self.leftConstraint!.constant
}
```

Is there a way in Swift that I can do this on one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original code works because in Obj-C, messages sent to nil [will return 0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW22).

Swift doesn't allow nil messaging. Instead, you can use optional chaining along with the nil-coalescing operator:

```
let leftConstraintConstant: CGFloat = self.leftConstraint?.constant ?? 0
```

This is even better because you're being explicit about what the code should do: propagate the nil value, and default to 0.